# After deploying via ClickOnce, where are the dlls stored on the client machine?

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I read somewhere that config data is stored under user account->Local Settings->Application data, but can't find where the dlls, exes and resource files are going.

I know ClickOnce uses an application store and a data directory to store its application data, but are these accessible to the client? Are they browseable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The dlls exes etc are all stored in the same folder. On my machine the root for each app is:

C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Local\Apps...

You can of course browse these with explorer...

Comment: Don't be too harsh on yourself. These directories are ridiculously obscure.

Answer (score 3):

On XP it is

c:\Documents and Settings\UserName(Sometimes called "Owner")\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\